# Wpf align content in different containers

Tags: wpf, layout

Whats the best way to align controls vertically that exist in different containers, in WPF/XAML?

In my case i have several Expander Controls with a Grid inside. In the grid there are Labels and Textboxes.
The grid row/column is setup as "Auto"

The Expanders is placed in a MainGrid in a usercontrol

It looks like this:

```
-Expander---------------
| Foo   | BarBarBarBar |
| Hello | Hi           |
------------------------
-Expander2-------------
| SomeText | More text|
| Aaaaa    | Bbbbb    |
-----------------------
```

What i tried to describ with the above figure is that the rows in the different expanders aren't aligned (the "|" symbolizes the grid border), and that is because the column width is set to Auto in the grid.

Is there a way to align the gridcolumn in the different Expanders without hardcoding the width of the columns in the different grids?

Answer (score 0):

SharedSizeGroup on grid like [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: That doesn't seem to work when i have my Grids in different containers...in my case different Expanders

Comment: put Grid.IsSharedSizeScope=true in the grid that contains all your expander